# Similar to IBMi (AS400) can we do telnet on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ibm-midrange

From your development server we do telnet and connect to other server. Can we do similar thing via Visual Studio and access source and work on it?

Comment: This is more of a networking question than a VS question. But, Visual Studio works with files, not network connections. The simplest route would be to mount an SMB share to your server, but that's a terrible idea if more than one person is working on the project. Develop locally, then deploy.

Comment: you can write a [FileSystemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider) to give VSC a virtual file system to your telnet server

Comment: @3Dave Code for IBM i actually has a way to deploy sources and build on IBM i. This would allow local development, tied into git, and then deploy and build on remote.

Comment: I think it's helpful to be clear whether you're talking about Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, as they are very different products.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out two extensions for Visual Studio Code:

1. Code for IBM i. Connect directly to IBM i and access members, the IFS, as well as the ability to launch a pase shell (and subsequently tn5250) right from the Terminal. I should note that I am also the maintainer: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HalcyonTechLtd.code-for-ibmi
2. SSH FS. Connect directly to the IBM i IFS through SFTP to view and edit streamfiles: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs
3. If you have SSH installed on your system, you can use `ssh` right from the VS Code Terminal without any extensions.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this answer comes from the primary (if not sole) developer of Code for IBM i. There is nothing wrong with that; this is definitely a good and useful answer (and I would personally make the same recommendations), and it's not like there's any kind of commercial angle in here whatsoever. But it is [Stack Exchange policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/153413) to mention affiliations with products in answers.

Comment: @JohnY I have also updated my answer to note that I am the maintainer.